# Property 'loaded' does not exist on type 'HttpSentEvent'

Tags: angular, typescript

I am using angular http post with the following options:

```js
this.http
  .post<{ body: any }>(environment.api.file.upload, reqBody, {
    reportProgress: true,
    observe: 'events',
  })
  .subscribe((ev: HttpEvent<{ body: any }>) => {
    switch (ev.type) {
      case 1:
        this.progress = ev.loaded / ev.total;
        break;
    }
  });
```

When I try to get ev.loaded, it throws the following error:

`Property 'loaded' does not exist on type 'HttpSentEvent'`

The `ev.type === 1` is supposed to filter only HttpProgressEvent. But doesn't work.

Is there a way to use `HttpEvent` type and not get the error?

Comment: is 1 equal to `HttpEventType.UploadProgress` ? Perhaps you should use `case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:` etc

Comment: That worked. Thanks a lot. If you could put the comment as an answer, I'll mark it as Answered.

Comment: what worked? I don't even know what I did :p

Comment: Replacing `case 1:` with `case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:` worked.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using `HttpEventType.UploadProgress` instead of `1` solved the problem.

```js
this.http
  .post<{ body: any }>(environment.api.file.upload, reqBody, {
    reportProgress: true,
    observe: 'events',
  })
  .subscribe((ev: HttpEvent<{ body: any }>) => {
    switch (ev.type) {
      case HttpEventType.UploadProgress:
        this.progress = ev.loaded / ev.total;
        break;
    }
  });
```